Caching yarn and python pip in google cloud build
Currently building with cloud build takes arround 10 minutes (5 minutes frontend, 5 minutes backend). Is there anyway I can cache the yarn install and pip install so the build time cut significantly?
this is my current config for cloud build
steps:
  - name: "node:18.17.1"
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
        yarn install
        yarn run create-app-yaml
        yarn build
    env:
      - redacted

  - name: "python:3.10.11"
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
        python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
        python ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: ["app", "deploy"]
    timeout: "1600s"



Do you want to cash it for a single Cloud Build run or over multiple Cloud Build runs?

@guillaumeblaquiere single is enough since different trigger have different requirements

In that case, keep in mind that, by default, only the /workspace is kept between steps. Therefore, store your dependencies in this directory (or subdirectory of it) to keep the libraries in "cache"

@guillaumeblaquiere oh sorry, I mean same triggers but different build runs. For example, I want to use yesterday pip/yarn cache to be used in today, tomorrow or next build.

Between different build, you have 2 solutions:

Either you use Cloud Storage to store the dependencies data. At the beginning of the build, you load the lib and you store them (or their update) at the end. It's also a good idea to tar.gz your data before transferring them to Cloud Storage. A single object is fastest than multiple small ones. You can use the Artifact storage feature for that
Or create a container image with all the dependencies and use it as the step image in Cloud Build. This time, you need a side pipeline to prepare and build this step image.

